# How to move my navbar to the top left corner?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put my navbar on the top left corner of my screen and stretch it to the other side. **I'm new to CSS** (I literally have never made a functional or good looking website before either so this is for learning.) Please explain your entire solution thoroughly so I can learn more about CSS.

I don't know what to search up or try at all.

**Code Snippet**
(also on [GitHub](https://github.com/Squigole/htmlPractice1/tree/main))

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: rgb(175, 48, 175);
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.options {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="block" id="account">
    <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Squigole/htmlPractice1/defaultUser.png" alt="Default User Profile Image">
  </div>
  <div class="block" id="settings">
    <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Squigole/htmlPractice1/settingsIcon.png" alt="Settings Icon">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="options">
  <div class="newForm">
    <button>Make New Form</button>
  </div>
  <div class="selectForm">
    <button>Select A Form To Take</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Squigole and welcome to SO. If you haven't yet taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), please be sure to do so. Try to refrain from posting links to a repo. You can paste your code in the question and format it with either MarkDown or (preferably)  create a a *stack snippet* by clicking the `<>` icon in the question editor.

Comment: Browsers add default padding to the body, which is why your navbar has a gap. To remove it add css `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`  As an alternative, you may want to include a [Minimal CSS Reset](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-minimal-css-reset)  which provides a common baseline.

Comment: The CSS for the body worked wonders! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your css file add `float: left;` to your .navbar styles. It will float to left. And also :

```css
body {margin: 0;}
```

This will remove the html body default margin and if nothing is written before the `.navbar`, it will be shown at the top.